# (Swift) Handling user's tap on webView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have `webView` and a hidden `stackView(3 buttons)` in the bottom of webView on my screen.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
```

By default, `stackView` is hidden, and it should be visible when user taps somewhere on the webView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stackView.isHidden = true
    }
```

How can I handle user's tap to make my 'stackView' visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    tapGesture.delegate = self
    webView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
   } 

  @obj func handleTap() {
      stackView.isHidden = false
    }
```

don't forget to add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

if it doesn't work, you have to add following method because `WKWebView` already has its own gesture recognizers

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
  return true
}
```